# How to refresh view on submit in mvc .net?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I got following function

```
function success(result)
{
    $("#Div2").html(result);       
    reloadDisplayAverage();        
}

function reloadDisplayAverage()
{       
    var tdata = $('#form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            mCollection: tdata,
        },
        url: "Search/SearchMenu",
        success: function (result) { success(result);
    });

function success(result)
{       
    $("#Div1").html(result);
}
```

I have my submit button

```
<div id="Div2">
    <input type="submit" /> 
</div>
```

And then I have one empty div

```
<div id="Div1"> </div>,
```

When I debug I get proper result into the controller, now I don't know to place that result onto the view;.

In my controller I am using

```
  public ActionResult SearchMenu(SVM svm)
    {

        var sv = qr.QueryResult(svm);

         return view() // If I pass like this, I won't get result back to                     view 
      // return View(sv) If I pass like this, it won't be valid model for the view as in view is tightly bounded to SVM 

    }
```

Comment: Its a bit unclear what your doing. How are you calling your `reloadDisplayAverage()` function? Are you wanting to trigger that function when you click the submit button? And what data are you passing to the `SearchMenu` function? And why do you have 2 `function success(result)` methods?

Comment: I am waiting to trigger to submit button, on submit button it automatically triggers and sends all data to the controller, controller is processing all that input data and giving me the output string

Comment: is the output from controller plain html or any object?

Comment: What do you mean _it automatically triggers_? Is it doing a normal submit or do you have more scripts that are handling the buttons `.click()` event of the forms `.submit()` event. You need to edit your question with more detail.

Comment: No,I don't have any other script to handle click event

Comment: Okay, now I wrote same function on button click event, still it's fine, it gives the same result set but problems stays the same, I can't show that result on the view

Comment: If you have not handled the click event or the submit event, how would your functions ever be called.

Comment: I am not pro in scripting at all, perhaps I struggle with basics, but you can try that out, it works. It sends all input fields from view to the controller

Comment: Only if its doing a normal submit! Your not using any ajax at all.

Comment: Well, I could care less, the way I am doing should work, I just want to post to my results on the view, can you tell me anything that'll work for me /

Comment: @AjuJohn It's an  object.

Comment: Can you console the result variable in the success function and let us know the output.

Comment: On the formsubmit public ActionResult (SViewModel svm)  I get all inputs fields into the svm object I process it and I get result in  sv = searchresut (); Here is the problem I guess  " return View(sv) " If I pass this one, it won't be logical for the view to render this stuff but if I pass return view() it won't get the data back @AjuJohn

Comment: I have added some more stuff @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

HTML:

```
<div id="Div1"></div>  <!--Your result view goes here!!!-->
<button type="button" id="yourButtonId">Post</button>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#yourButtonID").click(function(){
    function reloadDisplayAverage() {       
        var tdata = $('#form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: tdata,
            url: "Search/SearchMenu",
            success: function (result) { 
            $("#Div1").html(result);
           }

        });                  
      }
});
```

Hope it helps;)

Comment: Nope, still the same, I don't get my result on the view

Comment: Well if I use<button type="button" id="yourButtonId">Post</button>  it actually doesn't post anything

Comment: <input type="submit" id="yourButtonID"/> this one works

Comment: @Nil :) you may use this like: <button type="submit" id="yourButtonID"></button> but this like is not right.   TYPE="SUBMIT" Reloads all your page, TYPE ="BUTTON" do nothing , only you should to handle function ONCLICK()

Comment: Well, still I can't post result onto the same page

Comment: I am thankful that you're helping me out, will you check my edits  ?